# Wordpress Random post (last 3 days posts)

Tags: get-posts, php

i want show last 3 days posts Randomly.
how can i edit this code?

```
<?php
$randompost = array(
'numberposts' => 2,
'type' => 'news',
'orderby' => 'rand',
'year' => date( 'Y' ),
'week' => date( 'W' ),
);
$rand_posts = get_posts( $randompost );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code for show last 3 days post. Best of luck...

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'type' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'order' => 'rand',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '3 days ago'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below:

```
$today = getdate();
$randompost = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'before'     => '3 days ago',
            'after'    => array(
                'year'  => $today['year'],
                'month' => $today['mon'],
                'day'   => $today['mday'],
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'numberposts' => 2,
    'type' => 'news',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
  );

$rand_posts = get_posts( $randompost );
if ( $rand_posts ) {
foreach ( $rand_posts as $post ) : 
    setup_postdata( $post );
    ?>
    <!-- Your Markup Here -->
    <?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

See more details [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/)